# Having an issue parsing through this json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have created a var that is equal to `t.json`. The JSON file is a follows:

```json
{
    "groups": {
        "customerduy": {
            "nonprod": {
                "name": "customerduynonprod",
                "id": "529646781943",
                "owner": "cloudops@coerce.com",
                "manager_email": ""
            },
            "prod": {
                "name": "phishing_duyaccountprod",
                "id": "241683454720",
                "owner": "cloudops@coerce.com",
                "manager_email": ""
            }
        },
        "customerduyprod": {
            "nonprod": {
                "name": "phishing_duyaccountnonprod",
                "id": "638968214142",
                "owner": "cloudops@coerce.com",
                "manager_email": ""
            }
        },
        "ciasuppliergenius": {
            "prod": {
                "name": "ciasuppliergeniusprod",
                "id": "220753788760",
                "owner": "cia_developers@coerce.com",
                "manager_email": "jarks@coerce.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my goal was to pars this JSON file and get value for "owner" and output it to a new var. Example below:

```
t.json = group_map
group_id_aws = group(
            group.upper(), 
            "accounts", 
            template, 
            owner = group_map['groups']['prod'], 
            manager_description = "Groups for teams to access their product accounts.",
```

The error I keep getting is:  `KeyError: 'prod'`

Comment: `owner` occurs 4 times in the json,  so which one are you referring to ?

Answer (score 0):

You get a key error since the key 'prod' is not in 'groups'
What you have is

```
group_map['groups']['customerduy']['prod']
group_map['groups']['ciasuppliergenius']['prod']
```

So you will have to extract the 'owner' from each element in the tree:

```
def s(d,t):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if t == k:
            yield v
        try:
            for i in s(v,t):
                yield i
        except:
            pass

print(','.join(s(j,'owner')))
```

Comment: I completely understand why this was giving that key error but is there any way to exclude that account name and just iterate through owners ? I would not be able to list each account name like "customerduy" to get to the owner

Comment: A bit cryptic since I am using a tablet, sorry. It's a recursive search through the dict that returns all items with a certain key

Answer (score 0):

Owner occurs 4 times, so here is how to get all of them.

```py
import json

# read the json
with open("C:\\test\\test.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# get all 4 occurances
owner_1 = data['groups']['customerduy']['nonprod']['owner']
owner_2 = data['groups']['customerduy']['prod']['owner']
owner_3 = data['groups']['customerduyprod']['nonprod']['owner']
owner_4 = data['groups']['ciasuppliergenius']['prod']['owner']

# print results
print(owner_1)
print(owner_2)
print(owner_3)
print(owner_4)
```

the result:

```
cloudops@coerce.com
cloudops@coerce.com
cloudops@coerce.com
cia_developers@coerce.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is loaded in variable `data`, you can use a recursive function
that deals with the two containers types (dict and list) that can occur
in a JSON file, recursively:

```py
def find_all_values_for_key(d, key, result):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if key in d:
            result.append(d[key])
            return
        for k, v in d.items():
            find_all_values_for_key(v, key, result)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            find_all_values_for_key(elem, key, result)


owners = []
find_all_values_for_key(data, 'owner', owners)

print(f'{owners=}')
```

which gives:

```
owners=['cloudops@coerce.com', 'cloudops@coerce.com', 'cloudops@coerce.com', 'cia_developers@coerce.com']
```

This way you don't have to bother with the names of intermediate keys, or in general the structure of your JSON file.

You don't have any lists in your example, but it is trivial to recurse through
them to any dict with an `owner` key that might "lurk" somewhere nested
under a a list element, so it is better to deal with potential future changes
to the JSON.